# Get text from span bracket in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I don't know if this is often asked but I just can't figure out how to get the text info of an span bracket in the html code using python with selenium.

For example following code:

```
<li class="addetailslist--detail">
area
<span class="addetailslist--detail--value">
72,05 m²
</span>
</li>

<li class="addetailslist--detail">
rooms
<span class="addetailslist--detail--value">
2,5
</span>
</li>
```

Since I have multiple elements of "addetailslist--detail" on the page, I want to address them by using the words "area" or "rooms". Then I want to get the specific text from the class "addetailslist--detail--value" (e.g. 72,05m² and 2,5). I just can't figure out, how to address them the proper way. Can someone quickly help me on that one?

This is how far I have come:

```
area = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'area')]")
```

But this just delievers the whole element...

Answer (score 0):

To extract the texts e.g. *72,05 m²* and *2,5* from all of the `<span>` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.addetailslist--detail span.addetailslist--detail--value")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='addetailslist--detail']/span[@class='addetailslist--detail--value']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hi DebanjanB,

thanks for your reply! 
So far so good, but can you also tell me how to get the associated texts to a specific value? For example, when I just want to get the 72,05m² for the keyword "area"?

Comment: @LaBa Sounds like a different question all together. Can you raise a new question please?

Comment: Technically, I did it in this question. "Since I have multiple elements of "addetailslist--detail" on the page, I want to address them by using the words "area" or "rooms"."